# Are the concurrent tasks on the same Uvicorn worker using the same python context?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, fastapi, uvicorn, python-contextvars

I have using FastAPI for a web api and I am using also python context vars.  I know Uvicorn workers can fulfill many requests on multiple concurrent tasks.

Are those tasks are running in the same context ? 
If I set a context var in one task, It can be read in the other?

Comment: Have you found the solution? I've got `ValueError: <Token var=<ContextVar name='var' at 0x3e722df974f0> at 0x3e7222676d80> was created in a different Context` while using uvicorn and hypercorn workers

Comment: we made a different implementation, I will share a pseaudo solution later